# Intendation Error in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

So I have this code snippet from a Python3  script, which sadly produces a "expected indented block" error. The usual answer seems to be that you either indented wrong or mixed tabs and spaces. I checked both of those but my intendation seems fine and I am only using 4 spaces to indent, no tabs.
Anyone got an Idea whats wrong?

```
for submission in submissions:
    currentUser = submission.author.name
    if currentUser in uniqueUsers:
        # Do Nothing
    else:
        uniqueUsers.append(currentUser)

for user in uniqueUsers:
    print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **pass** keyword whenever you don't want to do anything

```
for submission in submissions:
    currentUser = submission.author.name
    if currentUser in uniqueUsers:
        pass
        # Do Nothing
    else:
        uniqueUsers.append(currentUser)

for user in uniqueUsers:
    print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `pass` insted of the `Do nothing`

```
for submission in submissions:
    currentUser = submission.author.name
    if currentUser in uniqueUsers:
        pass
    else:
        uniqueUsers.append(currentUser)

for user in uniqueUsers:
    print(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `# Do Nothing` actually doesn't do anything, this should work:

```
for submission in submissions:
    currentUser = submission.author.name
    if not currentUser in uniqueUsers:
        uniqueUsers.append(currentUser)

for user in uniqueUsers:
    print(user)
```

Or as other people mentioned, you can also use the keyword `pass`.

Comment: `currentUser not in uniqueUsers` is a single expression using the two-word `not in` operator, rather than having to negate the result of `currentUser in uniqueUsers`.